# why I cannot render the first layer

Tags: rendering, interface

After I rendered an animation in second layer, my render always render the second layer. I changed my camera setting and clicked 1st layer and then click render, but it still pops out the rendering of my second layer (my animation render).

How can I change back to render my first layer again? There are some pictures about my interfaces below, if they help.

[image]
[image][image]

Link to .blend file:

[image]

Comment: basically i have one animation in the second layer and a static picture in the first layer. after i done with the animation, i try to render my first layer picture but no matter how i try, my result is always a picture from already rendered animation rather than the first layer i want to render. Looking for solution

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6063" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6063/)

Comment: someone plz answer my question. I am so desparate

Comment: thx, i will wait for both you and other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go in the *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Post Processing*, and deactivate *Sequencer*. I quote the Blender manual: "Sequencer
Renders the output of the Video Sequence editor, instead of the view from the 3D scene’s active camera."

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the problem I had for 3 days. I am wondering what is this for? when should I re-activate it? Thanks for ur patience and valuable time. Wish you good day

Comment: You should make google researches, it would have helped you to find the problem  ;)  about Sequence: Renders the output of the Video Sequence editor, instead of the view from the 3D scene’s active camera.